# set Title when encode Web URL QR code android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I want to set the title when i encode a Web URL. I Use [QRCodeEncoder](http://pastebin.com/e2rVtSVA) class to encode the contents. I don't find anything to set title for the web URL.   I use below code to encode the input text field content and generate image.

```
// check validation for input string 
            if (URLUtil.isHttpUrl(inputWebURL)) {
                QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(
                        inputWebURL, null, Contents.Type.TEXT,
                        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), smallerDimension);
                try {
                    bitmapCreatedImage = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
                    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCreatedWebUrl);
                    myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapCreatedImage);

                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

How I set Title for the Web URL QR encoding?
Thanks.

Comment: What title are you referring to? URLs don't have a title per se.

Comment: like: google is the title 
web address: http://google.com when i decode google QR CODE. @SeanOwen SIR.